# How to add posix threads into eclipse on windows (MinGW)

Tags: c, eclipse, windows, pthreads, mingw

Alright, so i'm running Eclipse Mars.1 (with MinGW compiler) on windows 8.1 OS and i'm trying to enable usage of POSIX threads. 
I've downloaded pthreads win32 from : https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32 since windows doesn't have pthread library included as linux does. After i downloaded the .zip file i've extracted the files like this:

1. pthreadGC2.dll into C:\MinGW\bin
2. pthread.h , sched.h, semaphore.h into C:\MinGW\include
3. libpthreadGC2.a into C:\MinGW\lib

Back to the Eclipse, i've right clicked the project -> properties -> C/C++ build -> settings -> MinGW C linker , now here comes the problem, i have no idea what should i put into Libraries/Miscellaneous section. Eclipse is recognizing `#include <pthread.h>` (its not red color - underlining it) and pthread.h functions, but once i try to build it, it says this :

15:10:11 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project ASD ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -o ASD.exe qweqwe.o -lpthread 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: **cannot find -lpthread**
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

15:10:11 Build Finished (took 122ms)

I can't figure out what am i doing wrong, i've tried changing library name (in the linker settings tab) to pthreadGC2, but if i do that Eclipse just underlines pthread_create and says that it is undefined reference to _imp_pthread_create.

If anyone tried and succeeded doing this, please share your wisdom. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know eclipse, so just a further hint: with `gcc`, you shouldn't just *link* libpthread (with `-lpthread`) but instead use the special option `-pthread` that *also* links libpthread. Of course this won't help as long as libpthread isn't found by the linker, so it's really just a hint for later.

Comment: If I were compiling with `gcc` and I think mingw is based on gcc.  then the desired parameters would be: `-L\MinGW\lib -lpthreadGC2`  or since pthread is a 'special' parameter, then:  `-pthread`

Comment: I've tried every god damn combination already, i have no idea why it is not working. Is there any compiler suitable for eclipse that has pthread integrated in itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any compiler suitable for eclipse that has pthread integrated in itself?

Yes. Get your GCC (for Windows) from  [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) or from [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/). Then in Eclipse-CDT just add `-pthread` (not `-lpthread`) to the **Miscellaneous** -> **Linker flags**. As @FelixPalmen says, `-pthread` is a linker option that takes care of `pthread` linking. No others settings are necessary. The default include and library paths will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use the MinGW installer to download it.